# The file is not registerable as an ActiveX component

Tags: vb6, spreadsheet

I know this is old technology, but I am trying to do it any way.  I have an old VB 6 program that uses the OWC11 spreadsheet control.  It works great on my Windows 7 machine but now I am trying to move the project over to a Windows 8 machine.  The project does not load successfully and the problem is the OWC11 control.  When I go to Project->Components, and try to add the OWC11.DLL, I get the error message "The file is not registerable as an ActiveX component".

Just to make sure, I re-installed it successfully, then successfully registered it using RegSRV.  I also exported the piece in the registry on my Windows 7 machine for the OWC control and imported it on the Windows 8 machine.

Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I quit VB6 and then right clicked and ran VB6 as Administrator.  Then everything worked.  Why oh why if you are running as an Administrator account doesn't all your programs run as Administrator?

Comment: This "solution" suggests that it was never registered properly.  I suspect you either registered it into some user's virtualstore by running regsvr32 without elevation or else you ran the 64-bit regsvr32 and it didn't do anything at all (or both).

Answer (score -1):

OWC are deprecated:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_sustained_engineering/2009/06/30/office-web-components-lifecycle/

> The most important thing to be aware of is that the Office Web Components technology has been deprecated. This means that only security fixes are being made to all versions of OWC, and no future versions of OWC will be produced. If you are using OWC, you should begin migrating to a new technology as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, I am moving to VB.net, but I am just trying to keep this as a back-up.

Comment: You could try installing Office 2007 and OWC on Windows 8, but I don't think you'll be able to get it working.